# Splice NOT removing certain characters

Tags: javascript

I'm working on some codewars problems and I came to this 'remove noise thing', I guess the point is to escape backslash \ and use **replace** method, which was easy. But I didn't want to use **replace**, instead I found myself in trouble trying to remove items with **splice** method.

Funny thing is, when I debug in Chrome dev tools, step by step I see items get removed, but **console.log** spits out certain characters($/·|ªl) problematic to remove, and at the end gets returned and join with those characters. Why is that?

```js
function removeNoise(str) {
  var base = "%$&/#·@|º\ª";
  var arr = str.split('');

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var item = arr[i];
    var condition = base.indexOf(item);
    if(condition + 1) {
      //works like a charm
      //arr[i] = '';

      arr.splice(i,1); 
      //this thing wont work
      //when debugging it removes the items from the array
      //console log print no removing
    }
  }
  return arr.join(''); 
}

removeNoise('he%$&/#·@|º\ª\llo'); //=> $/·|ªllo
```

Comment: Just a quick note: If you want to remove noise, remember that in 99/100 cases it is easier and more reliable to define what you want in the string, not what you would like to remove from the string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using `splice` to *remove* entries from your array, but you're then incrementing `i` for the next loop. If you remove the entry at index 5 from a 10-entry array, what was the entry at index 6 is now at index 5 (of what's now a 9-entry array), so you don't want to increment your index.

The solution is to use a `while` loop and only update `i` if you *don't* `splice`:

```js
function removeNoise(str) {
  var base = "%$&/#·@|º\ª";
  var arr = str.split('');

  var i = 0;
  while (i < arr.length) {
    var item = arr[i];
    var condition = base.indexOf(item);
    if (condition + 1) {
      // Remove this entry, reuse same value for 'i'
      arr.splice(i,1); 
    } else {
      // Don't remove this entry, move to next
      ++i;
    }
  }
  return arr.join(''); 
}

var result = removeNoise('he%$&/#·@|º\ª\llo');
var pre = document.createElement('pre');
pre.appendChild(
  document.createTextNode(result)
);
document.body.appendChild(pre);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So much about reading books, and not applying. I remember reading about this as one of the common problems when I was reading N. Zakas book, and I fell straight into the trap. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

You're removing characters from your array. This will throw your indexer variable `i` out of sync with the characters you want to test. Easy way to fix is to start at the end of the array working your way to the beginning.

Change your for loop to this.

```
for(var i = arr.length -; i <= 0; i--) {
```

```js
function removeNoise(str) {
  var base = "%$&/#·@|º\ª";
  var arr = str.split('');

  for(var i = arr.length - 1; i <= 0 ; i--) {
    var item = arr[i];
    if(base.indexOf(item) >= 0) {
      //remove the offending character
      arr.splice(i,1); 
    }
  }
  return arr.join(''); 
}

removeNoise('he%$&/#·@|º\ª\llo'); //=> $/·|ªllo
```